# API to know the amount of free stoarge space on my windows device

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am creating a UWP application. I have a use case where I need to print the amount of free local storage available in GB on the windows device on which the app is running. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the DriveInfo class. Following this link will provide you with examples [System.IO - DriveInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo?view=netframework-4.8). Remember to take into consideration how to print the  free storage if the device has more than one internal storage device.